# How can I diff a single file with magit?

Tags: emacs, git-diff, magit

Say I've made a number of unrelated changes to uncoupled files in my git repo. I want to review and commit each of the files separately.

I run `magit-status`, and get a list of changed files. But the only magit diff commands I can find (`d` and `D`) diff entire revisons, not individual files.

I want the output of `git diff <filename>`, but in the magit diff buffer. How can I get magit to diff only one file?

Comment: What about using **e** on `magit-status` for Ediff dwimming?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Magit enables you to "review and commit each of the files separately" directly from the `magit-status` buffer, without the need for any separate diff buffers.

You just expand the file(s) you're interested in (with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, which shows you the diff for the file at point); then you can stage the bits of it that you want to commit (either the whole file, or individual hunks, or even a marked region) with <kbd>s</kbd> to stage (or <kbd>u</kbd> to unstage). Repeat for all the changes involved in that commit and, once everything necessary has been staged, press <kbd>c</kbd> to begin the commit.

You might prefer the visibility *cycling* behaviour you get by using <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> (repeatedly) instead of the simple toggle you get by default with <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

---

If you really do want to view the diff for a file in a separate buffer, you can do that from the file's buffer by calling `magit-diff-buffer-file` directly, or using the "diff" option (<kbd>d</kbd>) in `magit-file-popup`. e.g.:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m d") 'magit-diff-buffer-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m f") 'magit-file-popup)
```

---

Also note @assem's comment below:

> You might also be interested in `magit-ediff` which is bound to <kbd>e</kbd> by default, and opens an ediff session for the diff/file at point.

---

Some other alternatives available in Emacs by default (i.e. not Magit) are:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to call `vc-diff`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `vc-ediff` for the ediff equivalent
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ediff-revision` to create an ediff session with more options

I bind `vc-ediff` to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>C-=</kbd> so that the two variants have similar key bindings.

Comment: I didn't know about TAB.

Comment: Right, I thought that might be the case. That's pretty much the "killer app" aspect of magit you were missing out on, there! :) You can stage or unstage whole files, individual hunks within a file, or even the marked region. You should skim through http://magit.github.io/magit/magit.html as you're probably also missing out on some other nice features.

Comment: I've just been using a cheat sheet. I didn't know what the "section visibility" commands meant, and I just thought that `s` didn't work in my version of magit.

Comment: It sounds like your cheat sheet could make things clearer for people who don't already know how it works. You should write to the author and suggest improvements.

Comment: You might also be interested in `magit-ediff` which is bound to `e` by default, and opens an ediff session for the diff/file at point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it helps my a lot by using vc-diff

Comment: eleforest: You're welcome. You may also find it useful to bind a key sequence to `vc-ediff`, as that has no default binding (I use `C-x v C-=`).

Comment: Any idea how to keep `magit-ediff` from rearranging my windows?  It closed all the windows and replaced them with its own in a different layout, instead of just taking the windows over.

Comment: Peter Becich: You could undoubtedly have code to remember and restore the window configuration either side of the ediff call, but personally I just rely on `winner-mode` for this sort of thing. A quick `C-c <left>` or two always puts things back the way they were, and it works for everything.

Answer (score 24):

I recommend watching the [video](http://vimeo.com/2871241) by the creator of magit.
It's 20 min and it shows you the work-flow as it was intended.

Also, a small tip: you can use <kbd>1 2 3</kbd> to change
the diff verbosity of the current heading.

Another small tip: if you're not happy with the size of the hunks,
you can stage arbitrary regions by - *that's right* - marking a
region and pressing <kbd>s</kbd>. It's magic.
I didn't know about this option for a while, I was actually
dropping back to console and doing `git add -p` the old fashioned way.

Comment: It's sad that the last magit screencast was 4 years ago.  As a community Emacs needs to embrace screencasts more.

Answer (score 3):

There are definitely advantages to not going against the grain when using tools, as is exemplified by the other answers.

On the other hand, sometimes you just want to tell your editor what to do, and have people on the internet answer your questions instead of telling you want to do something else.

*magit* provides a menu interface for doing things to the current file through `M-x magit-file-popup`. The keys you need to press from here are "du". This may well be too many key presses for you, if this is the case you can call `magit-diff` directly like so:

```
(defun magit-diff-given-file (&optional file)
  (interactive)
  (unless file
    (setf file buffer-file-name))
  (magit-diff-working-tree "HEAD" nil (list (file-relative-name file (magit-toplevel file)))))
```

You might like to define your own function and keybinding for this.

`magit-diff` has advantages over `vc-diff` because if allows you to jump to the location of the diff.

Comment: `vc-diff` also allows you to jump to the location of the diff. (Which is possibly a new feature.)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this dozens of times for the "sometimes you just want to tell your editor what to do, and have people on the internet answer your questions instead of telling you want to do something else."